# How turn on GPS programmatically in my android application?

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, android-broadcast

If we use this code we see a message: **searching for GPS**. However, the **GPS** symbol is merely shown; **GPS** doesn't actually work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);   
}
```

Why isn't it working ? And how to make it work correctly ?

Comment: You can not enable and disable gps grammatically after kitkat os version.

Comment: please help  me out there is  any root access is to be done for getting Gps active programmatically  enable or disable it does't working in 4.1.2

Comment: @user3578377: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: yes, thanks for answer  Y.S. (your valuable information)

Answer (score 1):

That's not allowed anymore. If you take a look at [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35924), this hack was subverted in Android 4.4. It still works on older OS versions, though you shouldn't be using it anywhere now. To quote that report:

> This doesn't work ... however, it can cause stuff to react as if the GPS status changed -- for example, the **HTC One S** will show the GPS icon in the status bar, even though the GPS is still disabled.

That explains why you can see the GPS icon even though it isn't actually ON. Now as for why you ***can't*** do that ...

Android's GPS technology periodically sends location data to Google even when no third-party apps are actually using the GPS function. **In many Western countries this is seen as a major violation of privacy.** That's why Google made it mandatory to get the user's consent before using the GPS function. The following dialog is seen whenever the user turns GPS on:

[image: GPS user permission]

And hence it is no longer possible to *programmatically* change the GPS settings, as by necessity it requires the user's permission. What the programmer *can* do is direct the user to the GPS settings by calling

```
startActivity(context, new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

and let the user make a choice.

As an interesting point, if you try sending the `GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE` broadcast on the new OS versions, you get a

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
    not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE
```

error. As you can see, its a `SecurityException` with a *permission denial* message.

Comment: Actually, it was fixed before 4.4 IIRC. Developers using the Play Services fused location API also have an option of having Play Services pop up a dialog asking for permission to turn on location tracking, via `SettingsApi`.

Comment: Indeed. My bad ... :\

Comment: @CommonsWare: would be honored if you take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30473371/3287204) ... :)